# heroku fails to create app from default node-js-sample

Tags: node.js, heroku

I forked node-js-sample and made just added index.htm with some content
When I click the button "Doploy to heroku" app fails to build with following error:

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
   engines.node (package.json):  4.0.0
   engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

   Resolving node version 4.0.0...
   Downloading and installing node 4.0.0...
   Detected package-lock.json: defaulting npm to version 5.x.x
   Bootstrapping npm 5.x.x (replacing 2.14.2)...
   npm 5.x.x installed
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.0.0
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at 
https://nodejs.org/
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.0.0
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at 
https://nodejs.org/
ERROR: npm is known not to run on Node.js v4.0.0
Node.js 4 is supported but the specific version you're running has
a bug known to break npm. Please update to at least 4.7.0 to use this
version of npm. You can find the latest release of Node.js at 
https://nodejs.org/
-----> Change to Node.js build process 
   Heroku has begun executing the "build" script defined in package.json
   during Node.js builds.
   Read more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1573
-----> Build failed

   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

   If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
   https://help.heroku.com/

   Love,
   Heroku

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed
```

From what I understand heroku try to runs my code with incorrect version of node.js, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository hasn't been updated in 4 or more years and still depend on node.js 4 and lists the same on the [package.json](https://github.com/heroku/node-js-sample/blob/4d7f65990fe80978cc0c0e6c0d8cd0e7e07fa218/package.json#L12). It is a compatibility issue, before deploying change it to 6.0.0 and try, you might have luck.

Comment: Thank You a lot. That was the problem. Funny thing is that it worked several days ago on heroku, just fine. They must have update environments since then

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue recently which was a real pain, found a solution here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support

> *Currently, supported versions are 10.x, 12.x, 13.x, and 14.x.*
>
> *You should always specify a Node.js version that matches the runtime
> you’re developing and testing with.*

Updated node globally and specified the engine in package.json like:

```
"engines": {
"node": "10.20.x"
```

},

Hope this helps someone